# String array to Json using JS error converting half only

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, react-fullstack

I have a problem with my below code when I want to convert array into JSON. Please see my code below:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;" id="body">
  <p id="GFG_UP1" style="font-size: 16px;">

  </p>
  <p id="GFG_UP2" style="font-size: 16px;">
  </p>
  <button onclick="gfg_Run()">
    Convert
  </button>
  <p id="GFG_DOWN1" style="color:red;
    font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
  </p>
  <p id="GFG_DOWN2" style="color:red;
    font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
  </p>
  <script>
    var el_up1 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP1");
    var el_up2 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP2");
    var el_down1 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN1");
    var el_down2 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN2");
    var array1 = [34, 24, 31, 48];
    var array2 = [23, 43, 65, 52];
    var numberArray1 = [];
    var numberArray2 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      numberArray1[i] = "number" + i + ':' + array1[i];
    }
    el_up1.innerHTML = "Array = [" + array1 + "]";;
    function gfg_Run() {
      el_down2.innerHTML =
        JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray1));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
      numberArray2[i] = "number" + i + ':' + array2[i];
    }
    el_up2.innerHTML = "Array = [" + array2 + "]";;
    function gfg_Run() {
      el_down2.innerHTML =
        JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray2));
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

is giving output:

```
["number0:23","number1:43","number2:65","number3:52"]
```

not both arrays are being converted

like it should give output both:

```
["number0:34","number1:24","number2:31","number3:48"]
["number0:23","number1:43","number2:65","number3:52"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "text-align:center;" id = "body">
<p id = "GFG_UP1" style = "font-size: 16px;">

</p>
<p id = "GFG_UP2" style = "font-size: 16px;">
</p>
<button onclick = "gfg_Run()">
Convert
</button>
<p id = "GFG_DOWN1" style = "color:red;
font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>
<p id = "GFG_DOWN2" style = "color:red;
font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>
<script>
var el_up1 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP1");
var el_up2 = document.getElementById("GFG_UP2");
var el_down1 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN1");
var el_down2 = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN2");
var array1 = [34, 24, 31, 48];
var array2 = [23, 43 ,65 ,52];
var numberArray1 = [];
var numberArray2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
numberArray1[i] = "Phone" + i + ':'+array1[i];
}
el_up1.innerHTML = "Array = [" +array1+"]";;


for (i = 0 ; i < array2.length; i++)
{
numberArray2[i] = "Phone" + i + ':'+array2[i];
}
el_up2.innerHTML = "Array = [" +array2+"]";;
function gfg_Run(){
el_down1.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray1));
el_down2.innerHTML =
JSON.stringify(Object.assign(numberArray2));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```